# How to compare values by two rows

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

How to select rows that have the column [nbr] contains different values.

It may be that some [st_id] have only one record.

```
   st_id       trc      dir  nbr    
   88900     4009114     1   2  
   88900     4009114     2   2    
   88000     4009115     1   2    
   88000     4009115     2   2    
   88300     4009113     1   3   
   88300     4009113     2   2   
   88400     4009110     1   4  
   88500     5120012     1   1
   88500     5120013     2   2
   88600     1270081     1   3
```

**Result:**

```
   st_id       trc      dir  nbr    
   88300     4009113     1   3   
   88300     4009113     2   2   
   88500     5120012     1   1
   88500     5120013     2   2
```

Comment: can you explain the logic a little more. :) Thanks

Comment: Group by your dad based on st_id first and then drop duplicates in nbr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first use `drop_duplicates` to get a single row for each `st_id, nbr` pair, then `groupby` just the `st_id` to find instances where more than one `nbr` exists:

```
(df
 .drop_duplicates(["st_id", "nbr"])
 .groupby(["st_id"])
 .filter(lambda x: x.nbr.nunique() > 1)
)

   st_id      trc  dir  nbr
0  88300  4009114    1    2
4  88300  4009113    1    3
7  88500  5120012    1    1
8  88500  5120013    2    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
       st_id      trc  dir  nbr
    0  88900  4009114    1    2
    1  88900  4009114    2    2
    2  88000  4009115    1    2
    3  88000  4009115    2    2
    4  88300  4009113    1    3
    5  88300  4009113    2    2
```

You can use crosstabulation if you are using a pandas dataframe. And then convert the crosstabulation table into a DataFrame. Notice, that you have conceptually converted the `nbr` variable onto a category (nbr=2 or nbr=3) For this reason I rename the new columns (which tell you to which nbr class they belong 2 or 3) as columns: `nbr_2`, `nbr_3`

```
    pd.crosstab([df.st_id, df.trc,df.dir], df.nbr)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.columns=['st_id', 'trc', 'dir', 'nbr', 'nbr_2','nbr_3']

    >>>

       st_id      trc  dir  nbr  nbr_2  nbr_3
    0  88000  4009115    1    2      1      0
    1  88000  4009115    2    2      1      0
    2  88300  4009113    1    3      0      1
    3  88300  4009113    2    2      1      0
    4  88900  4009114    1    2      1      0
    5  88900  4009114    2    2      1      0
```

You can play with the columns involved in the cross tabulation depending on what you are looking for.

If you want to sort all rows which nbr = 2

Then you can use:

```
    df[df.nbr==2]

    >>>

       st_id      trc  dir  nbr
    0  88900  4009114    1    2
    1  88900  4009114    2    2
    2  88000  4009115    1    2
    3  88000  4009115    2    2
    5  88300  4009113    2    2
```

or

```
    df[df.nbr==3]
```

...